# ExtJS -- create separate column header menus for each column

Tags: extjs

Is there a way to create separate menus for grid column headers? One instance of the menu is shared amongst all columns, so if I check a menu item in one column, that item is shown as checked in all columns.

I know I can show/hide menu items as needed on "beforeshow", but that doesnt help here.

thanks

Comment: Short answer is no, not without a lot of hacking. Maybe you could re-create the items you need in `beforeshow` as required.

Comment: @stackato: You can get solution BUT you will need to create custom menu on header click and show it by column header.Try this

Comment: thanks Evan. I used beforeshow to first remove all the menu items then add them back in. I also mark the menu items that were previously selected as checked using an object i had created to save the checked items for each column.